# How to add Datatables Custom row rendering / aggregates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add a custom row to a serverside rendered data table, inorder to show the total amount of a column
the following is how the table headers are
Date | Name | **Amount** | Ref |

```
 <table id="tableExport_filter">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Amount</th>
       <th>Ref</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr></tr>
    </tbody>                                   
  </table>
```

to get the data using AJAX

```
var dataTable = $('#tableExport_filter').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'serverMethod': 'post',

 'ajax': {
       'url':'app/functions/collections_by_agent.php',
       'data': function(data){}
    },
'columns': [
      
       { data: 'date_created'},
       { data: 'name'},
       { data: 'amount' }, 
       { data: 'ref' }
    ],
});
```

I need help to append a **row** to the table and Add the Sum total of the amount column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this by using the table footer `<tfoot>` instead of adding a new row to the body of the table.

Steps:

1. In your HTML table, add an empty footer after the closing `<tbody>` tag:

```html
<tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
 </tr>
</tfoot>
```

2. Add a `footerCallback` option to your DataTable:

```js
var dataTable = $('#tableExport_filter').DataTable({

  // your existing options go here

  "footerCallback": function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
    var api = this.api();
    $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(
      api.column( 2 ).data().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
        return a + b;
      }, 0 )
    );
  }

} );
```

In this function, you use `var api = this.api();` to gain access to the DataTables API functions from within the table itself.

You then select column index 2 (i.e. the 3rd column) of the footer as the target for the sum.

Finally, you use a `reduce` function to sum up all the values from data column index 2. That `0` at the end of the function is the starting value used when performing the initial step of the `reduce` function.

The footer callback is documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback).

The reduce function is documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/reduce()).